# Why is org-cite style not working?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm currently trying to manage my bibliography with `org-cite` and I'm checking both the documentation ([1](https://orgmode.org/manual/Citation-export-processors.html) and [2](https://orgmode.org/manual/Citations.html)) together with the blog post to introduce the feature ([3](https://blog.tecosaur.com/tmio/2021-07-31-citations.html)). There, they claim that you can use some basic styles within the cite notation and I'm able to use the default (`[cite:@key]`) and some of them for export, e.g., no-author (`[cite/na:@key]`) or no-cite (`[cite/n:@key]`) export to HTML without any problem. But whenever I try to use author (`[cite/a:@key]`), the export fails with:

> `org-cite-basic-export-citation: Wrong type argument: characterp, raw`

I thought there might be a problem with the `.bib` file, but I can use it perfectly within a `LaTeX` document, so I have no clue where the mistake is. Has anybody faced the issue? Is there any solution? The `org` version I'm using is 9.5.5, if that is relevant.

The debug backtrace first lines:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument characterp raw)
  mapconcat(#f(compiled-function (key) #<bytecode 0x1fc64fa916d8a0c>) ("lang1987linear") ", ")
  org-cite-basic-export-citation((citation (:style "a" :begin 525 :post-blank 1 :end 550 :contents-begin 533 :contents-end 548 :parent ...) (citation-reference ...)) ("a") #s(org-export-backend :name latex :parent nil :transcoders (... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) :options (... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) :filters (... ... ... ...) :blocks nil :menu (108 "Export to LaTeX" ...)) (:export-options nil :back-end #s(org-export-backend :name latex :parent nil :transcoders ... :options ... :filters ... :blocks nil :menu ...) :translate-alist (... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) :exported-data #<hash-table eq 0/4001 0x1563dcae5189> :input-buffer "product.org" :input-file "product.org" :latex-class "notes" :latex-class-options nil :latex-header nil :latex-header-extra nil ...))
  org-cite-export-citation((citation (:style "a" :begin 525 :post-blank 1 :end 550 :contents-begin 533 :contents-end 548 :parent (paragraph ... ... #1 ...)) (citation-reference (:key "lang1987linear" :begin 533 :end 548 :post-blank 0 :parent #1))) nil (:export-options nil :back-end #s(org-export-backend :name latex :parent nil :transcoders (... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) :options (... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) :filters (... ... ... ...) :blocks nil :menu (108 "Export to LaTeX" ...)) :translate-alist ((bold . org-latex-bold) (center-block . org-latex-center-block) (clock . org-latex-clock) (code . org-latex-code) (drawer . org-latex-drawer) (dynamic-block . org-latex-dynamic-block) (entity . org-latex-entity) (example-block . org-latex-example-block) (export-block . org-latex-export-block) (export-snippet . org-latex-export-snippet) (fixed-width . org-latex-fixed-width) (footnote-definition . org-latex-footnote-definition) (footnote-reference . org-latex-footnote-reference) (headline . org-latex-headline) (horizontal-rule . org-latex-horizontal-rule) (inline-src-block . org-latex-inline-src-block) (inlinetask . org-latex-inlinetask) (italic . org-latex-italic) (item . org-latex-item) (keyword . org-latex-keyword) (latex-environment . org-latex-latex-environment) (latex-fragment . org-latex-latex-fragment) (line-break . org-latex-line-break) (link . org-latex-link) (node-property . org-latex-node-property) (paragraph . org-latex-paragraph) ...) :exported-data #<hash-table eq 0/4001 0x1563dcae5189> :input-buffer "product.org" :input-file "~/product.org" :latex-class "notes" :latex-class-options nil :latex-header nil :latex-header-extra nil :description nil :keywords nil :subtitle nil ...))
  org-cite-process-citations((:export-options nil :back-end #s(org-export-backend :name latex :parent nil :transcoders (... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) :options (... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) :filters (... ... ... ...) :blocks nil :menu (108 "Export to LaTeX" ...)) :translate-alist ((bold . org-latex-bold) (center-block . org-latex-center-block) (clock . org-latex-clock) (code . org-latex-code) (drawer . org-latex-drawer) (dynamic-block . org-latex-dynamic-block) (entity . org-latex-entity) (example-block . org-latex-example-block) (export-block . org-latex-export-block) (export-snippet . org-latex-export-snippet) (fixed-width . org-latex-fixed-width) (footnote-definition . org-latex-footnote-definition) (footnote-reference . org-latex-footnote-reference) (headline . org-latex-headline) (horizontal-rule . org-latex-horizontal-rule) (inline-src-block . org-latex-inline-src-block) (inlinetask . org-latex-inlinetask) (italic . org-latex-italic) (item . org-latex-item) (keyword . org-latex-keyword) (latex-environment . org-latex-latex-environment) (latex-fragment . org-latex-latex-fragment) (line-break . org-latex-line-break) (link . org-latex-link) (node-property . org-latex-node-property) (paragraph . org-latex-paragraph) ...) :exported-data #<hash-table eq 0/4001 0x1563dcae5189> :input-buffer "product.org" :input-file "~/product.org" :latex-class "notes" :latex-class-options nil :latex-header nil :latex-header-extra nil :description nil :keywords nil :subtitle nil ...))
```

Comment: To debug this problem, you need to do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, redo the export and add the backtrace that you will get to your question.